# Can I configure JSch to automatically reconnect on connection failures?

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am using the [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) API for Java for SFTP connections. Sometimes the server may be down for a second or the connection may be busy. In these cases I would need to **re-connect** to the server three times at least before I decide the connection has failed.

Does JSch provide any configuration option to do this automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSch has no such configuration option, but you can simply do this yourself.

```
Session s = new Session(...);
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_TRIES; i++) {
    try {
       s.connect();
       break;
    }
    catch(JSchException ex) {
       if(i == MAX_TRIES - 1)
           throw ex;
       continue;
    }
}
```

After executing this block, either the session is connected or a JSchException is thrown.